# I want both to be true before it shows up

Tags: php

I have several of these in my site but this one isn't working.  It's only checking if the the level is over 499 if so the href shows up but I don't want it to show up unless both the level is over 499 and checkfiftyplv is greater than 0.  Any and all help is appreciated.

```
    <? if ($user_level > 499 && $checkfiftyplv > 0) {  ?>
    <a class="leftmenu" href="lv5050pgame.php">LV 5050 Points<!_-fiftyplv-_!></a>
           <? } ?>
```

Comment: The code you've posted should work, can you check the values your comparing against when this fails.  It may be something to do with the values - so try `var_dump($checkfiftyplv);` and `var_dump($user_level);`

Comment: I did add the var_dump to both and in the box where this outputs it said string(3) "505"